Media 3 Exoplayer Lifecycle change bug on Jetpack Compose
I set up Exoplayer with classic way.
val exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build()
exoPlayer.repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_ONE
exoPlayer.playWhenReady = false
exoPlayer.setMediaItem(MediaItem.fromUri(uri))
exoPlayer.prepare()
exoPlayer.play()

When on app going background, I pause exoPlayer.
Lifecyle.Event.ON_PAUSE -> exoPlayer.pause()

This is my setup.
When I take app to background player, player pause. After I take app to foreground player still pause but video frame a little bit played. Each time I repeat this loop the video plays a little bit.
I'm listening to onIsPlayingChanged. As a result, isPlaying is false when I take app to background. There is no further change. Same in onPlaybackChanged and currentPosition.
Everything is working correctly. However, the video frame is playing a little. How can I fix this ?

How about using
DisposableEffect(Unit) {         onDispose {             exoPlayer.release()         }     }
